# If probability of winning a cricket match is $0.65$ , then find the probability of losing that cricket match.

Tags: probability

Q) **If probability of winning a cricket match is $0.65$ then what is the probability of losing that cricket match?**

Ans) We know that: P(getting an event)$+$ P(not getting an event)$=$ $1$

Similarly we can also say that :
P(winning a match)$+$ P(losing that match)$=$ $1$ .

Therefore in this above question ,

P(winning the match)$=$ $0.65$ . Therefore we can easily say that

P(losing the match)$= 1-0.65 = 0.35 $ .

**My doubt**:

This method is fine. But I can't understand that while in case of solving this types of questions on Probability why we also don't take the condition:
P(the match will draw) ? In this above question we are just taking the conditions of 'wining the match' and 'losing the match' but we are not taking the condition that 'the match will be draw'. Is the answer of P(losing the match) correct? I am not sure. Please do let me know. If I am wrong then please help me out with the correct solution.

Comment: And cricket is worse than that: not only can you *draw*, but a further distinct possibility is that you *tie*: https://www.lords.org/mcc/the-laws-of-cricket/the-result

Comment: Yes. You are correct @Henry. But why don't we take that condition in case of solving questions on Probability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In (simple) more general terms, we have a [probability space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space) that consists of a sample space $\Omega$ (the possible outcomes), an event space $\mathcal{F}$ (a set of events), and a probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ (assigning each event a probability). In this case, it seems that they take $\Omega = \{\text{Win}, \text{Lose}\}$.

The general statement the answer mentions is, for all events, $\mathbb{P}(A) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(A^c)$. Then for $A = \{\text{Win}\}$, $A^c = \{\text{Lose}\}$, and the answer is correct.

Your assumption (which is much more in line with the real world), is that $\Omega = \{\text{Win}, \text{Lose}, \text{Draw}\}$. Then for $A = \{\text{Win}\}$, $A^c = \{\text{Lose}, \text{Draw}\}$, and the answer is indeed not correct.

Answer (score 0):

**Complementary events** are events that are mutually exclusive (they can't happen at the same time) and exhaustive (together they cover all possible events).

If we are talking about two complementary events (say $E$ and $E'$), then yes

$$P(E) + P(E') = 1$$

The problem here is that winning and losing are not complementary. If you don't win, it's not guaranteed you lost. There may have been a draw, tie whatever the game allows for.

If $E$ denotes winning $E'$ denotes not winning (which would include the cases of losing, tie, etc).

So,

$$\begin{align*}
P \,(\text{not winning}) &= 1 - P\,(\text{winning})\\[0.3cm]
&= 1-0.35 \\[0.3cm]
&= 0.65
\end{align*}$$

But we don't have sufficient information to find the probabilty of losing.